# Symfony 3 - OneToOne relation update

Tags: php, symfony

I have a OneToOne relation:

Company entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Address", mappedBy="company",cascade={"all"})
 */
private $address;
```

Address entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Company", inversedBy="address")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="companii_id_companii", referencedColumnName="id_companii")
 */
private $company;
```

When i am trying to update the values, it is inserting a new address instead of updating the existing one.

What did i do wrong?

UPDATE

CompanyForm Type:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add("companie_uid", HiddenType::class);
    $builder->add("companie_denumire", TextType::class, array('label' => 'companie_denumire'));
    $builder->add("companie_cui", TextType::class, array('label' => 'companie_cui', 'required' => false));
    $builder->add("companie_j", TextType::class, array('label' => 'companie_j', 'required' => false));
    $builder->add("companie_mail", EmailType::class, array('label' => 'companie_mail', 'required' => false));
    $builder->add("companie_website", TextType::class, array('label' => 'companie_website', 'required' => false));
    $builder->add("companie_status", HiddenType::class);
    $builder->add("companie_descriere", TextAreaType::class, array('label' => 'companie_descriere', 'required' => false));
    $builder->add("companie_telefon", TextType::class, array('label' => 'companie_telefon', 'required' => false));
    $builder->add("companie_iban", TextType::class, array('label' => 'companie_iban', 'required' => false));
    $builder->add("companie_banca", TextType::class, array('label' => 'companie_banca', 'required' => false));
    $builder->add("file", FileType::class, array('label' => 'companie_file', 'mapped' => false, 'required' => false));
    $builder->add("save", SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'companie_save'));
    $builder->add(
        $builder->create('address', CompanyAddressType::class, Array('by_reference' => false,))
    );
}
```

AddressForm Type

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add("adresa_adresa", TextType::class, array('label' => 'adresa_adresa', 'required' => false));
    $builder->add("adresa_telefon", TextType::class, array('label' => 'adresa_telefon', 'required' => false));
    $builder->add("adresa_fax", TextType::class, array('label' => 'adresa_fax', 'required' => false));
    $builder->add("adresa_email", EmailType::class, array('label' => 'adresa_email', 'required' => false));
}
```

Controller Edit Code:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $company = $form->getData();
            $em->flush();
```

Solved! I just need to remove:

```
Array('by_reference' => false,)
```

Comment: the owning side of the relation is Address entity. what do you do when you update the address?

Comment: I am not updating the address without Company. So do i need to change the owning side of relation to company? Can you give me an example please?

Comment: @Senzo you should provide example code related with the issue in first place.

Comment: Why did you set `'by_reference' => false` on `address` field? I don't think you meant it.

Comment: @JakubMatczak Thank you. That was the problem. I forgot to remove that.